# Does prstat SIZE value in Solaris increase indicate memory leak?

Tags: c, memory, memory-leaks, solaris

In my program, I create 100 threads, then wait for all of them to join and then repeat this operation again.

In each of the threads, I create some memory and free it. I am fairly sure, all the memory which I am creating in those threads are getting freed.

But, the SIZE output and RSS output of prstat are continously increasing. They are increasing regularly by 4M

What do these values indicate? Does it mean there is some memory leak?

EDIT:

My original intention was to find out what is the meaning of SIZE & RSS columns in prstat output. Also, does increase in the value shown by SIZE confirm the presence of memory leak in the code?

Comment: Hello Jay, can you follow up your question here ? It is currently in a quite frustrating state ... Clarifying what you mean with "indicate" would be helpful too.

Comment: @jilliagre, Sorry, was busy with other stuff, so couldn't access the site. Now, I have clairifed. Hope it is Ok. Also, I don't know who downvoted your answer. That is so far the closest answer which I have got.

Comment: I'm quite sure zvrba downvoted my answer because he understands "indicate" in your question to mean "might be a symptom of" while I understand it to mean "is without any doubt a symptom of". Unfortunately, by repeating "indicate" in your edit, you do not clarify that point :-(

Comment: @jilliagre, I have re-edited my question. I meant "is without any doubt a symptom of". Feel free to edit more if required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, prstat SIZE increase doesn't necessarily indicate a memory leak. You can only guess that there might be a memory leak. Moreover, when using the standard Solaris malloc/free libraries, freed memory is not returned to the OS so the SIZE metric is never decreasing. You should really post a sample source code exhibiting the issue to help figuring out if you really experiencing a memory leak.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, continuously increasing memory usage indicates a memory leak.

Comment: Or a program that simply is doing more.   Not all programs have a steady state of memory usage - it's only a leak when you fail to free the memory when you stop using it, not when you just keep using more.  From prstat alone, you can't tell which case it is.

Comment: @alanc: Have you actually read the description of what his program does?

Comment: @zvrba: the open poster description isn't enough to diagnose a memory leak. Without seeing the code, you shouldn't affirm there is one.

Comment: The OP wrote: "I am fairly sure, all the memory which I am creating in those threads are getting freed."  If his main() function does nothing else than creating and waiting for threads (as he also wrote), then yes, this IS enough to suspect a memory leak.

Comment: Nobody claim a memory leak is not to be suspected. Your assertion is stronger than that, the reason why I voted it down.

Comment: "indicate" is not the same as "prove".

Comment: Then you should replace "indicate" by something less ambiguous. A memory leak is always causing a continuous memory usage increase. A continuous memory increase usage is not necessarily caused by a memory leak.

Comment: You should rather learn to interpret things within their proper context.

Comment: @zvrba, Thanks for posting an answer. Can you pls through some more light since, I have re-edited my question? I am very sorry, if the way I had framed the question earlier caused confusion.